# How to pass in the current date React JS Mongo

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, date, mongoose

I am using a mongo database for comments and I'm trying to display the date of each entry in the database

I have the following Mongo Schema

```
let CommentsData = new Schema({
    team_id: {
        type: String
    },
    comment: {
        type: String
    },
    date: {
        type: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentsData);
```

I have the below function on the front end which is called when a button is clicked to insert a new comment - is there a function in ReactJS I can use instead of the 'whatgoeshere?' part next to date that would insert the current date (at the time the button is clicked) into the database?

```
    const CommentInsert = (team_id, comment) => {
        axios
            .post('http://localhost:3999/todos/addComment', {
                team_id: team_id, comment: comment, date: whatgoeshere?
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log(`Successfully added comment`)
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(`Error adding Comment.`))
    }
```

My route is shown below

```
todoRoutes.route('/addComment').post(function (req, res) {
    let toBeAdded = new Comment(req.body);
    toBeAdded.save()
        .then(() => {
            res.status(200).json({'comment added successfully' });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding comment failed');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates are a variable subject that is far out of the scope of this question. Doing your dates this way might cause you trouble if you are going to support multiple time zones.

When the date is generated on the client-side it is bound to the locale for that user. I would highly recommend against doing this as it will cause dates to jump for the same string of comments (depending on what time zone the user commented from).

I would let the endpoint you are sending this message to handle generating the date so that it is consistent. You might also consider standardizing it to UTC as well instead of server time (in case your server time ever changes due to an update or issue).

I am not sure what server-side language you are using, but to do it in JS would be:

```
const date = new Date().getTime();
```

That would give you a timestamp for that exact moment.

Comment: Thank you, I have figured out how to do it the way you suggested