# How to check if there was document made in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mern, social-networking

So I made an social network application with MERN stack and I want to make sure that user can only post once a day. So I would need validation for that. How do I make that user can post only one post from 00:00 to 23:59 the same day. Meaning he can post on 4th July in 23:59 and 5th July 00:01.

Comment: Show your attempt. This is not a code writing service. We help solve specific issues you run into if you present a proper [mre].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211358/how-to-pass-in-the-current-date-react-js-mongo

Comment: https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mongodb/working-with-dates

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296212/cant-check-if-document-exists-in-cloud-firestore-database-and-with-reactjs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.